# What does boost::asio::ip::tcp::available () returns when there are 0 bytes available

Tags: sockets, boost-asio

In the boost documentation it states that the return value is 0 if there is an error, if that is true what will it return in the case where there are 0 bytes to read from the socket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no bytes available to be read, then [`basic_stream_socket::available()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/available.html) will return `0`, as `0` is the number of bytes that may be read without blocking.  The documentation does not mean to imply that `0` is only returned if an error occurs when it states:

> The number of bytes that may be read without blocking, or 0 if an error occurs.

A brief glance at the [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/4e1e7d731fcc5c0104567856de476f7ce8806d72/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L649-L656) shows that Boost.Asio uses [`ioctlsocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`ioctl()`](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/ioctl.2.html) to determine the amount of bytes available.  Neither of these system calls are documented as not being able to successfully return `0`.

Comment: I had to account for `0` being successfully returned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22796634/1053968).  Due to how Boost.Asio may turn `0` byte reads into a no-op at the application level, I had to guarantee the buffer size was at least `1` by taking the max of `socket.available()` and `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot detect connection failure without actually attempting to read.

This is inherent to network streams.

Related (though talking about Java):

- [What does 'end of stream' mean when working with sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649320/what-does-end-of-stream-mean-when-working-with-sockets/649431#649431)

This section of Boost Asio Docs about short reads/short writes and end-of-stream errors is also enlightening:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html